# How to set Wrappanel child textbox width as *?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to make First child Wrappanel Textbox Size should be * and stretch as much as space avail . Second wrappanel consists only buttons and should appear size as Auto . Please help to achieve this

```
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1,1,1,1"  Width="Auto" >
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Command: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox MinWidth="130" MinHeight="30"></TextBox> <!-- Size should be * and strech as much as space avail-->
        </WrapPanel>


        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1,1,1,1" Width="200"  >
            <Button  Content="Prev" />
            <Button Content="Next" />
            <Button   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=textConsole}" Content="Execute" />
            <Button  Content="Clear Output" />
        </WrapPanel>

    </WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use WrapPanel? Why not use Grid?

Comment: I need to wrap Textbox and buttons when minimum widht available.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this out, but I think it should work.

```
    <Grid Margin="1,1,1,1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Command: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="130" MinHeight="30">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{DynamicResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ActualWidth" Value="130">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            <TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

For the other WrapPanel, I'm not too sure what you wanted. Shouldn't the buttons already be as large as it requires?